# Regex ex, first number inside brackets after certain text

Tags: regex

I have been trying to get this to work using different tools and sites such as regexr.com but haven't been able to figure it out.

I have a massive block of text somewhere in the text is:

```
javascript:device_popup(256, 3409)
```

I am trying to get the 256 sometimes there will be multiple of the above but the number for the comma will always be the same for each block of text.

I have tried variations of the following

```
/\[(.*?)\]/g
/javascript:device_popup\[(.*?)\]/g
/javascript:device_popup\(\.(*?),)/
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first attempt matches everything between square brackets. The second attempt does the same only if preceded by "javascript:device_popup". In the third attempt, your syntax is incorrect.

You can modify your regular expression as follows:

```
/javascript:device_popup\((\d+)/
```

Comment: I tried the below and it gave me NULL

<?php

$data = 'javascript:device_popup(256, 3409)';
preg_match('/javascript:device_popup\((\d+)/g', $data, $matches);

var_dump($matches);

?>

Comment: Remove the `g` modifier. https://eval.in/297949 And use `preg_match_all()` to get all matches.